# Broadcast Receiver as inner class in Android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

In my code there is an inner class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`.

And I have added the following line to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name="OuterClass$InnerClass android:enabled="true"/>
```

But I am receiving the following error:

> unable to instantiate receiver org.example.test.OuterClass$InnerClass

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: the AndroidManifest.xml line got lost somehow and is not displayed - can you please check

Comment: hey Martin, thanx, please chk it now..

Answer (score 33):

An (non-static) [*inner class*](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-inner-classes/) cannot be instantiated by Android via the AndroidManifest.xml ([Android developer documentation on BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)):

> *You can either dynamically register an instance of this class with
>   Context.registerReceiver() or statically publish an implementation
>   through the  tag in your AndroidManifest.xml.*

So you can dynamically register the receiver. In my application I wanted to do the same for using Google's Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) and my original AndroidManifest.xml contained:

```
<application...>
    <receiver android:name=".MyC2dmReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

I removed that *receiver* section and dynamically registered the receiver as follows:

```
public class AndroidService extends IntentService
{
    ... 
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
        filter.addAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION");
        filter.addCategory("com.example.myapp");
        this.registerReceiver(new MyC2dmReceiver(), filter, "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND", null);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    }

    public class MyC2dmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a question about this. What happens to the object of MyC2dmReceiver that was registered after it receives an intent? Does it stay alive and ready to receive another one or does it get available for deletion by the GC and we need to register another instance of it?

Answer (score 18):

The `$` notation doesn't denote an inner class, but a static nested class. So there are in theory 2 ways to solve this particular problem:

1. Denote it as a real inner class, i.e. `OuterClass.InnerClass` (not sure though if Android will eat that since the instantiation of an inner class is pretty more complex than just doing `Class#newInstance()`.
2. Declare the class to be a static nested class instead, i.e. add `static` to `class InnerClass {}`. This way the `OuterClass$InnerClass` must be able to create a new instance out of it.

If that doesn't solve the problem, then apparently Android simply doesn't eat it that way. I'd just extract it into its own standalone class then.

#### See also:

- [Java tutorial - Nested classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)
- [Answer with code example how to instantiate an inner or static nested class using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097982/is-it-possible-to-create-an-instance-of-nested-class-using-java-reflection/2098082#2098082) (as Android should be doing "under the covers")

Comment: Thanx for the answer BalusC :) But in my case I wanna call an Async class which is inner class of my activity using Alarm. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: I can confirm that it is possible to use static nested class using the Outer$Inner notation; in my case, I'm creating an AppWidgetProvider receiver and the inner class extends the outer class to specify a unique AppWidgetProvider for each sizes.

Answer (score 7):

Could it be that there is just a dot and a closing quote missing? Like

```
<receiver android:name=".OuterClass$InnerClass" android:enabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Very much possible and small enough to miss. Good one!

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me:

```
public class OuterClass {
    public static class InnerStaticClass extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            final Location location = (Location) intent.getExtras().get(LocationClient.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <receiver android:name=".OuterClass$OuterClassConnector$InnerStaticClass" />
```

Comment: What is `OuterClassConnector` here?

Comment: I don't find that in my code now, it's been changed in the past 2 years a lot. I think it was generated somehow by android when I implemented GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks interfaces. But now I use a solution with explicit intent class: new Intent(mContext, InnerStaticClass.class);

Comment: Thanks.. this works for me.
But i also defined:
 
android:enabled="true"

in receiver tag defined in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I've just met the same problem.

I have a service to communicate with many activities, and I also have a receiver in my service as inner class. when the receiver get message ,it has to call the method of service. so it goes on like this :

**1. Service code:**

```
public class XXService extends Service{

     // I want the inner receiver call the methd of XXService,
    // so I have to write this constructor like this.

    private XXService instance;
    public XXService(){instance = this;}
    public XXService getInstance(){
       return instance;
    }
    public void sayHello(){
    }
    public static class XXReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        onReceive(......){
            XXService.getInstance.sayHello();
        } 
   }
}
```

**2. Register receiver in manifest.xml :**

```
<receiver android:name=".XXService$XXReceiver" android:enabled="true"/>
```

Comment: This seems really impressive to me. May be just what I wanted. I'll try this and revert if it works.

Comment: This is working. Thank you. Well I didnt write `android:enable="true"` yet it is working. Any idea? Or that was just for being on the safer side?

Comment: `Non-static method 'getInstance()' cannot be referenced from a static context`. Both `instance` and `getInstance()` need to be static. But then you may get: `Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak`

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use **$**...
If you get warning for a class which is not actually an inner class, it's because you are using **uppercase characters in your package name**, which is not conventional.

I tried also to change only the first letter of the package name to be lower case, the warning and error disappeared.