# Is it possible to define a broadcast receiver as an inner class in manifest file?

Tags: android, android-manifest, broadcastreceiver

I want to create a broadcast receiver as an inner class in my main activity. 
But I have problems defining the broadcast receiver in manifest xml file,
because android can't find it.

Code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    ...

    public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ....
        }

    }

    ...
}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".org.danizmax.myapp.MyActivity$Receiver" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="org.danizmax.myapp.BROADCAST_INITIAL_DATA"></action>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I tried with:

- .org.danizmax.myapp.MyActivity$Receiver
- org.danizmax.myapp.MyActivity$Receiver
- .MyActivity$Receiver
- .Receiver

I saw others also having similar problems, but did not find any answers.

So is it possible? If not, what's better way to use broadcast receivers?

Thanks!

Comment: Try making your inner class Static.  Also, what package attribute do you define in your manifest?  That determines the starting point of your android:name on the receiver.

Comment: Ah it works now with static class and receiver name defined as .MyActivity$Receiver. Add your comment about making inner class Static to your first answer so I can send you some reputation. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment.. you only get notified of comments on questions if it is your question, or if you use an @username at the beginning of the comment.

Comment: it is work but it is not starting after reboot , how can I do that

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

The receiver android:name attribute should look like `.path.to.class.MyClass$MyInnerClass`

Comment: Inner class must be Static...

Comment: Also remember `android:enabled="true"` on the `<receiver>`

Comment: @danizmax ;Bear ;Victor it is work but it is not starting after reboot , how can I do that

Comment: How do you overcome this with a non-static inner class?

Answer (score 12):

If you want to this with a *non-static* inner class, you can't do it via the AndroidManifest.xml. You can however dynamically register the BroadcastReceiver:
[Receiver as inner class in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10851904/1239858)

Comment: Great reference, but this won't work for media buttons in [Jelly Bean](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13576130).

Comment: You need to make the class static and public for android to instantiate the broadcast receiver when it is statically declared in the manifest file.as android instantiates it it needs to be a static class otherwise outer class object will also be required to be instantiated.

Answer (score -2):

The better way to use `BroadcastReceiver`s would be to make it its own class.  That way the code is better organized and you can possible reuse it.

Comment: Not if you need to call [a method in your main activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058743/how-do-i-register-in-manifest-an-inner-media-button-broadcastreciver#comment21174031_15058783). And not in [Jelly Bean](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13576130/636571)...