# Android-nested Class and Manifest file

Tags: android, android-manifest

Refactored my simple dial application and moved my custom 'ServiceReceiver' class so it is nested in my Main Class like so (partial code showing just nested ServiceReceiver class)

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                    Log.d("foo","incomingNumber : "+incomingNumber);

                    EditText incomingNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);

                    incomingNum.setText(incomingNumber);

                }
            },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }
```

My question is, after doing this, what changes need to be made to the manifest.xml?

Here is my existing (old) manifest file when ServiceReceiver was in a seprate file, class, not nested.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.foo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.foo.Main"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.foo.Main$ServiceReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and make the Receiver class as static

Comment: When I try and make nested ServiceReceiver static get the error Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById from the type Activity

Comment: But if I omit static, it compiles and I get the following runtime error :Unable to instantiate receiver, Can't instantiate; no empty constructor

Comment: Reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391974/is-it-possible-to-define-a-broadcast-receiver-as-an-inner-class-in-manifest-file

Comment: Can you try adding an empty constructor.