# Why can't android see this inner class?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a `GcmBroadcastHandler` inside my `Service`, like so:

```
public class SyncService extends Service {

// lots of other stuff in this class

    public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM received!");
            downloadChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The `SyncService` is located within a package called `service`.
I have declared the service and the receiver in my `AndroidManifest.xml` like so:

```
<application
android:name="com.appnl.myapp.CustomApp"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<!-- android.name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver" -->

<receiver
    android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.appnl.gcm" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
    android:name="service.SyncService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/service_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="service.SyncService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<!-- activity list -->
```

Yet, when android handles the incoming GCM message, I guess the following `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.appnl.myapp.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.appnl.myapp.GcmBroadcastReceiver" on path: /data/app/com.appnl.myapp-1.apk
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2493)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:159)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1392)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.appnl.myapp.GcmBroadcastReceiver" on path: /data/app/com.appnl.myapp-1.apk
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2488)
04-11 12:40:19.474: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    ... 10 more
```

Any ideas as to why it cannot find the `GcmBroadcastHandler` inside my `Service`? Is it because I have declared it correctly in the manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$` for declaring Inner Classes in manifest with Using its Outer class like..
chnage this

```
android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
```

into

```
android:name="packageName.SyncService$GcmBroadcastReceiver"
```

For more check this [Registering Inner class in manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391974/is-it-possible-to-define-a-broadcast-receiver-as-an-inner-class-in-manifest-file)