# app crash everytime it receive a push notification

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do a simple web view app based with push notifications. My app registers in background and do all the stuff, but when I send a push and my phone is supposed to show the push notification the app crashes. I've tried to debug and set a breakpoint in the `onReceive()` method, and I've also set breakpoints everywere but the app just crashes and don't stop anywere before doing it. I'm new in android studio and I don't understand at all the error messages so please if somebody can help me to find the error it would be greatly appreciated.

logCat:

```
05-04 14:41:46.349  30089-30089/com.example.alfredo.guiasandroid E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
05-04 14:41:46.349  30089-30089/com.example.alfredo.guiasandroid E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
05-04 14:43:34.879  10207-10207/? E/Launcher﹕ setWindowOpaque()
05-04 14:43:34.909  10207-10207/? E/Launcher﹕ MTP-LAUNCHER: media scanning not yet finished.
05-04 14:43:34.959  10207-10207/? E/Launcher﹕ setWindowOpaque()
05-04 14:43:44.879  30089-30089/com.example.alfredo.guiasandroid E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.alfredo.guiasandroid.MainActivity$GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.alfredo.guiasandroid.MainActivity$GcmBroadcastReceiver
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1777)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.alfredo.guiasandroid.MainActivity$GcmBroadcastReceiver
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1768)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 14:43:44.979  10104-10118/? E/﹕ Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
05-04 14:43:50.839  10207-10207/? E/Launcher﹕ setWindowOpaque()
```

mainfest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alfredo.guiasandroid" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission android:name="com.example.alfredo.guiasandroid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.alfredo.guiasandroid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


<application
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<!-- Required for applications which use Google Play Services. -->
<!-- <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> -->
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<receiver
    android:name=".MainActivity$GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <!--android:name=".MainActivity$GcmBroadcastReceiver" -->

    <intent-filter>
        <!--
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="com.example.alfredo.webapp" />
        -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.example.alfredo.guiasandroid" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<!--
<service android:name=".MainActivity$GcmIntentService" />
-->
    <service android:name=".MainActivity$GcmIntentService" />
</application>
</manifest>
<!--

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alfredo.guiasandroid" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
-->
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alfredo.guiasandroid"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

mainActivity.java:

```
    package com.example.alfredo.guiasandroid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    String SENDER_ID = "example_Number";

    /**
     * Tag used on log messages.
     */
    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";
    private WebView myWebView = null;

    TextView mDisplay;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context context;
    String regid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "hola coño");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialize variables
        context = getApplicationContext();
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        prefs = getPreferences(0);
        mDisplay = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

        // web view
        this.myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://mongini.net/guiasdelsur");

        //remove shared prefs
        /*
        SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.commit();
        */
        /*
        SharedPreferences clear_cache = getSharedPreferences("registration_id", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = clear_cache.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.commit();
        */


        // Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with
        //  GCM registration.
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground();
                Log.i(TAG,"ok");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");

        }
    }



    // You need to do the Play Services APK check here too.
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkPlayServices();
    }

    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {

        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "This device is not supported.");

                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service.
     * <p>
     * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
     *
     * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
     *         registration ID.
     */
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing registration ID is not guaranteed to work with
        // the new app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's {@code SharedPreferences}.
     */
    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the registration ID in your app is up to you.
        return getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    /**
     * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
     */
    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
     * <p>
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * shared preferences. com.example.alfredo.webapp.MainActivity
     */
    private void registerInBackground() {

        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {

                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);


                    msg = "Device registered, registration id=" + regid;

                    // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                    // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();


                    // Save the regid for future use - no need to register again.
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regid);
                    editor.commit();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                return msg;
            }
            // Once registration is done, display the registration status
            // string in the Activity's UI.
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute();
    }



    private String readStream(InputStream is) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int i = is.read();
            while(i != -1) {
                bo.write(i);
                i = is.read();
            }
            return bo.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use GCM/HTTP
     * or CCS to send messages to your app. Not needed for this demo since the
     * device sends upstream messages to a server that echoes back the message
     * using the 'from' address in the message.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
        // Your implementation here.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/example.php?host=localhost&dbname=db_name&user=user&pass=pass&idPush="+regid);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            /** Connecting to url */
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            readStream(in);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception url ", e.toString());
        }finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

    }


    /**
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * {@code SharedPreferences}.
     *
     * @param context application's context.
     * @param regId registration ID
     */
    //aqui peta
    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }



    public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                    GcmIntentService.class.getName());
            // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
            startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
            setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }
    }


    public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
        public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

        public GcmIntentService() {
            super("GcmIntentService");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
            // in your BroadcastReceiver.
            String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

            if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
             * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
             * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
             * recognize.
             */
                if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                            extras.toString());
                    // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                    // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                                + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    // Post notification of received message.
                    sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                }
            }
            // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
            GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }

        // Put the message into a notification and post it.
        // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
        // a GCM message.
        private void sendNotification(String msg) {
            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                    .bigText(msg))
                            .setContentText(msg);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }



    //back device button
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            this.myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608955/receiver-as-inner-class-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the inner-class `BroadcastReceiver`s only work if they are `static`.

In fact `$` marks a static inner-class.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4392499/603270

Comment: sorry what is AFAIK?

Comment: it means "As Far As I Know".  @shkschneider should not be using non technical acronyms in responses...

Comment: @eduyayo really? I see them all over the place. But good point anyway.

Comment: Thank you guys! It's always good to enter in stackoverflow because you are sure you are going to learn new things, and that's ok even for acronyms, cheers!