# Broadcast Receiver does not trigger when Mobile Screen Locks

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

When I install the app everything works fine. I am able to print Message body every time I send a message until I lock mobile screen. After that, the app stops printing incoming messages. I tried many ways to overcome this problem but with no luck. Please help me...

```
public class SmsReceiveActivity extends Activity{

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);

receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
final android.telephony.SmsMessage[] messages = new android.telephony.SmsMessage[pdus.length];

for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
    messages[i] = android.telephony.SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
    incomingMsgString += messages[i].getMessageBody().toString();
   }
    // Print Incoming message Body
  }
 }
}        
  getApplication().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the `BroadcastReceiver` [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), when you register a receiver with `registerReceiver()`,  "You won't receive intents when paused".  If you want a receiver that is independent of your activity, you should implement it as a named class and publish it in your manifest.  For example, create a named class with your anonymous `BroadcastReceiver`,

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
final android.telephony.SmsMessage[] messages = new android.telephony.SmsMessage[pdus.length];

for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
    messages[i] = android.telephony.SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
    incomingMsgString += messages[i].getMessageBody().toString();
   }
    // Print Incoming message Body
  }
 }
}
```

And in your manifest add the receiver inside your `application` tag

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/ >
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then when an SMS message is received your `onReceive` method will be invoked.  There you can package up the information you need and launch an intent to your `Activity` or `Service` for further processing.

Comment: Why are we doing this - SmsMessage[] messages. Why the array? Is it for multiple SMSs?

Answer (score 0):

Create your broadcast as static inner class and register it in manifest.  Try this link. [Receiver as inner class in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10851904/1239858)