# java.lang.InstantiationException: class has no zero argument constructor

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to use a `BroadcastReceiver` as an **inner class** to track the network state but I got the exception in the title.  What should I do to fix this problem?

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable()) {
            setupData();
            Log.d("Netowk Available ", "Flag No 1");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Your

> inner Broadcast receiver must be static ( to be registered through Manifest)

OR

> Non-static broadcast receiver must be registered and unregistered inside the Parent class

for this.

I was using an Inner broadcast reciver, without registering it within the class. Either make it static and register in Manifest , or Make it non static and register and unregister inside the parent class .

Comment: Had the same problem with an Activity implemented as an inner class. Same solution – declaring the inner class as static fixed it.

Answer (score 16):

A non-static inner class cannot be registered via the `AndroidManifest.xml`. You can either:

**Register it dynamically**  as outlined in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10851904/2707325), and remove the empty constructor.

Or,

**Make your inner class static**, and register it in the `AndroidManifext.xml`.

Comment: when i remove the empty constructor the same exception is happening

Comment: Aha, turns out that is the problem. An (non-static) inner class cannot be instantiated by Android via the AndroidManifest.xml (Android developer documentation on BroadcastReceiver). Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608955/receiver-as-inner-class-in-android) out, and dynamically register your receiver.

Comment: @KarimAbdellSalam I've edited my answer too, so make sure you accept my answer if it answers your question :)

Answer (score 1):

just make your Receiver Class static like:

`public [static] class ReceiverClass extends BroadcastReceiver`

Answer (score -2):

e~~I just meet that problem,and I refactor the class `NetworkChangeReceiver` to an another place