# Can't instantiate receiver: class has no zero argument

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

Although I know there are some answers out there already, I don't quite understand them as I am just a beginner in Android programming. I tried to instantiate my receiver using the following code:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.example.android.exampleapp.MainActivity$NetworkChangeReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

but it did not work. The logcat says:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.android.exampleapp.MainActivity$NetworkChangeReceiver:
    java.lang.InstantiationException:
        class com.example.android.exampleapp.MainActivity$NetworkChangeReceiver has no zero argument constructor
```

Part of my code in **MainActivity.java** is shown below:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    /* All my code that reacts when WiFi state changes are here */
}
```

I know this question might sound easy, but I seriously do not know how to resolve this error. I had read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947038/java-lang-instantiationexception-class-has-no-zero-argument-constructor) (which I think is kinda invalid - I do not have a empty constructor) and a bunch of other online tutorials but I still can't get it. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 10):

Change:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
```

to:

```
public static class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
```

Or, move `NetworkChangeReceiver` to be a `public` class in its own Java file.

Comment: What if i got non-static methods in `public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: @YikJin: Then you cannot register it in the manifest. You would have to use `registerReceiver()` in your activity, with a side effect that your receiver will only be watching for broadcasts while the activity is around (and, IIRC, in the foreground).