# broadcastreceiver for outgoingcall not fired

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

The BroadcastReceiver I created programmatically inside the Service didnot call onReceive method.I created a class that extends BroadcastReceiver inside Service class.Earlier when I just implemented it in manifest and ran the code it didnot work back then.Since Service runs in background continuously I thought the BroadcastReceiver would also run along with it.

*Edit:*
Now I get an exception after declaring permissions programmatically.The BroadcastReceiver is triggered but I get the following exception.Please look below the code.

*Code:*

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Jobin on 15-03-2018.
 */

public class PhoneListenerService extends Service{
    private PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener;
    private TeleListener teleListener;
    private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
    private File file;
    private OutgoingReceiver outgoingReceiver;
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        outgoingReceiver=new OutgoingReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
        registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver,intentFilter);
        file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        telephonyManager=(TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"AutoCall");
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            Log.e("File","Created");
            file.mkdir();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("File",file.getPath());
        }
        telephonyManager.listen(new TeleListener(getApplicationContext(),file.getAbsolutePath()),PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        Log.e("Oncreate","Service");

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.e("OnCommand","Service");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(outgoingReceiver);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("Out","Track");
            String phone_number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Toast.makeText(context,"Outgoing call identified",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

*Exception:*

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                          Process: com.js.globemaster.autocallrecorder, PID: 7086
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.js.globemaster.autocallrecorder.PhoneListenerService$OutgoingReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.js.globemaster.autocallrecorder.PhoneListenerService$OutgoingReceiver> has no zero argument constructor
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3681)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1903)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.js.globemaster.autocallrecorder.PhoneListenerService$OutgoingReceiver> has no zero argument constructor
                                                                                               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3676)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1903) 
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: do you have  PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS permission?

Comment: I declared it in manifest

Comment: it is dangerous, not enough to declare in manifest. Need to request it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS permission.

Because this permission is dangerous, you need to request it programmatically.

**Edit:**

For Broadcast Receiver add default constructor. And you don't add `<receiver>` to manifest when you are registering at run-time.

Comment: I havent declared permission programmatically for listening to incoming calls.But it is working.

Comment: Ia that not dangerous

Comment: @jobin https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS protection level:dangerous

Comment: I havent declared permission programmatically for READ_PHONE_STATE except in manifest,but I can check incoming calls.

Comment: @jobin Some permissions needs to be able to be requested at runtime (i.e. programmatically).... Imagine your phone cam firing without telling you it is starting... So just try what he said and see the results for yourself

Comment: Will try it now

Comment: It works now,but I get an exception:It says the receiver has no zero argument constructor.So what should i do now

Comment: @Afshin Edited.Please look into it

Comment: @jobin check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947038/java-lang-instantiationexception-class-has-no-zero-argument-constructor

Comment: The receiever is non static but it is reigistered inside the parent  i.e..class that extends Service class

Comment: If I am programmatically doing it do I have to remove <receiver>from  manifest?

Comment: @jobin O.O yea.... you never do both at same time.... and add default constructor too for your Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: It works bro...Thanks a lot.Could you edit your answer so that mark it as an answer