# Creating instance of subclass in Java by c.newInstance()

Tags: java

While creating instance of subclass Y

```
public class X implements I{
    ...

    ...
    public class Y implements I{
        ...

        ...
    }
}
```

by

```
o = c.newInstance();
```

where c is Y class I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.gmail.kubuxu.ms2d.Commands.VersionCommand$CCommand
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.gmail.kubuxu.ms2d.CommandProcessor.<init>(CommandProcessor.java:22)
    at com.gmail.kubuxu.ms2d.Conns.CommandServerProtocol.<init>(CommandServerProtocol.java:13)
    at com.gmail.kubuxu.ms2d.Conns.ClientConn.run(ClientConn.java:40)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone say what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This can't work anyway since the inner class is not static. Instantiation of it requires an outer instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class Y is a non-static nested class. You can't create it without an instance of the class X.

Depending on your needs, the easiest solution for you might be to make it static:

```
public static class Y implements I{
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Y` is non-static inner class of `X`, you cannot create instance of `Y` directly

like

```
Class clazz = Y.class
Y ref = clazz.newInstance();
```

You need to do as explained in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097982/is-it-possible-to-create-an-instance-of-nested-class-using-java-reflection)

```
Class<X> oc = X.class;
Class<?> c = Class.forName("X$Y");
Constructor<?> con = c.getConstructors()[0];
Y i = (Y)con.newInstance(oc.newInstance());
System.out.println(i);
```