# Instantiating a class in Java with reflection

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create a method that will instantiate a class based on a given interface. At the moment I am trying to instantiate a class based on a class name but I keep getting `ClassNotFoundException`.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
public class Message implements IExample{
    @Override
    public String showMessage() {
        return "merge";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Object mess = Class.forName("Message").newInstance();
}
```

**EDIT**

I have tried :

```
Object mess = Class.forName("com.MyExample.Message").newInstance();
Object mess = Class.forName("Project.MyExample.Message").newInstance();
Object mess = Class.forName("MyExample.Message").newInstance();
```

They all throw `ClassNotFoundException` and a window which tells me "Source Not Found" with a button (Edit Source Lookup Path..) that let's me browse documents.

Both the main class and `Message` classes are in a project called "Project" and a package called `MyExample`

Comment: Are you sure class `Message` is on the class path? Also, you need the fully qualified class name; `com.whatever.Message`

Comment: what is your package? where does your `Message.class` lives?

Comment: Are the class Message and the main method inside a common class ? if so, give a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097982/is-it-possible-to-create-an-instance-of-nested-class-using-java-reflection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the fully qualified class name to [`Class.forName(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29).

> **Parameters:** className the fully qualified name of the desired class.

If `Message` is in package `com.package`, that would be `com.package.Message`.

```
Object mess = Class.forName("com.package.Message").newInstance();
```

That class must be on the classpath when launching the application.

Answer (score 2):

If your Message class is in a package, you need to specify the full name, such as `edu.myschool.mypackage.Message`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the fully qualified name of the Class. If `Message`is in package `x.y` then you have to provide `x.y.Message`.

```
Object mess = Class.forName("x.y.Message").newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

The class name shouldn't include the ProjectName, just the package name structure that is defined in your src folder.

If you are using Eclipse, make sure you defined the src folder correctly in your project.
[Here](http://gullele.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/change-default-source-directory-srcjava-in-eclipse-for-java-project/) is how you can change the src folder for your app (if needed).

the Structure should be something like this:

```
Project
 |
 +-src
 | |
 | +-com
 |   |  
 |   +-MyExample
 |     |
 |     +-MyClass
 +-build
```

In this case, you should be able to say

`Class.forName("com.MyExample.MyClass").newInstance();`

It's very important how your structure in the src folder is defined and make sure you have the right src folder defined in your IDE project settings.