# Cannot import/reference class from external package

Tags: java, eclipse, kryonet

I have two packages mg.networktest and mg.networktest.server, both need access to the same class for registering/serializing classes that need to be send over the network. I think the best practice would be to create it on the server package and include it in the client.

However i cannot get the class referenced properly. I also tried adding another package but that is not allowed I think. But it just does not recognize my other package. The imports below all get `The import mg.networktest.server cannot be resolved`. I can get it to `import mg.networktest.*;` but that just references itself.

```
import mg.networktest.server; //This is the exact package
import mg.networktest.server.Network; //This is the physical class/.java name
import mg.networktest.server.Network.ChatMessage; //This is one of the classes inside the .java that needs to be included.
```

To be more clear:

- Package 1: (mg.networktest.server) has a Network.java with class ChatMessage.
- Package 2: (mg.networktest) needs the class ChatMessage from package 1.
- Package 2: (mg.networktest) cannot do: `import mg.network.server.*;`.
- How do i get access in package 2 (mg.networktest) to class ChatMessage from package 1 (mg.networktest.server)?

Comment: To import the whole package use `import mg.networktest.server.*;` (`.*` doesn't work recursively), but you already imported that `Network` class so where is the current problem?

Comment: @Tom I cannot do that and i did not import the Network class, that is the problem i have.

Comment: When I don't know that you're trying to achieve here and why it is not working. Which class exactly do you need and that is the error message you're receiving?

Comment: @tom i added a sum up of my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your import statement causes a compilation error, verify the following:

- You've used the correct syntax. For a single type name, use the syntax `import TypeName;`. To import type names on demand from a package or class scope, use the syntax `import PackageOrTypeName.*;`.
- You've named a package and/or class that currently exists. Check the path, and check the spelling.
- If the imported class is in a different Eclipse project or library, verify that it's on the build path for the importing class's project.
- Rebuild the projects containing the importing and imported classes. Usually this isn't necessary if you have *Build automatically* enabled.

Comment: I just realized I incorrectly named my question. It should have been different project instead of package. When I read point 3 everything fell into place, added the project to the build path and now I can import it correctly. Is this the correct way to reference a single class? I mean, I added a complete project to another where I only need a single class from that project. Should i have put this "shared" class in a separate project and add that buildpath to both my main projects?

Comment: Are you developing two executables, one for the client side and one for the server side? In that case, you would typically place the shared code in a separate library, included on path of both the client and the server. This specifies exactly what may be shared, and what is *not* shared. That in turns lets you know what will need to be re-installed if you make a change in any of the three projects.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to rebuild your current project structure. This is my `Network` class with the inner class `ChatMessage`.

```
package mg.networktest.server;

public class Network {

  public class ChatMessage {
    public void message() {
      System.out.println("Blub");
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my class from package `mg.networktest` that needs the `ChatMessage` class

```
package mg.networktest;

import mg.networktest.server.Network;
import mg.networktest.server.Network.ChatMessage;

class NeedChatMessage {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    final Network network = new Network();
    final ChatMessage chatMessage = network.new ChatMessage();
    chatMessage.message();
  }
}
```

You'll need to import the parent class `Network` and the inner class `ChatMessage` in order to use the inner class here.
Now you'll need to create a new instance of the parent class `Network` first to access the inner class with that instance. May check this question [Is it possible to create an instance of nested class using Java Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097982/is-it-possible-to-create-an-instance-of-nested-class-using-java-reflection) and the answers there to find other ways to create a new instance of the inner class.

**P.S.**

You could also make the inner class `ChatMessage` static

```
public static class ChatMessage {
    public void message() {
        System.out.println("Blub");
    }
}
```

Now you don't need the `Network` class anymore to access the inner class

```
import mg.networktest.server.Network.ChatMessage;

class NeedChatMessage {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    final ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
    chatMessage.message();
  }
}
```